# Symfony dynamic dropdown

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

Hi I want to get dynamic dropdown lists with cities depending on region. I try to follow official symfony documentation and add dynamic forms but I'm newbie in symfony and my coding skills didn't let me get what am I doing wrong, so I need some advise

City.php

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\CityRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=CityRepository::class)
 */
class City
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Region::class, inversedBy="cities")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
 */
private $parent;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

public function getParent(): ?Region
{
    return $this->parent;
}

public function setParent(?Region $parent): self
{
    $this->parent[] = $parent;

    return $this;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

Region.php

```
namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\RegionRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=RegionRepository::class)
 */
class Region
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\City", mappedBy="parent")
 **/
protected $cities;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get cities
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getAvailableCities()
{
    return $this->cities;
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->name;
}
```

and Form.type.php

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
{
    $builder
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('description', TextareaType::class)
        ->add('region',  EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Region::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'placeholder' => '')
;
 $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Region $region = null) {
        $cities = null === $region ? [] : $region->getAvailableCities();

        $form->add('city', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => City::class,
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices' => $cities,
        ]);
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $data = $event->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getRegion());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('region')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            $region = $event->getForm()->getData();

            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $region);
        }
    );
```

And in twig I have:

```
var $region = $('#offer_region');
    $region.change(function() {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var data = {};
        data[$region.attr('id')] = $region.val();
        $.ajax({
            url : $form.attr('action'),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            data : data,
            success: function(html) {
                $('#offer_city').replaceWith(
                    $(html).find('#offer_city')
                );
            }
        });
```

Ajax in POST return correct region value but still there is somthing I missed that city dropdown is always empty, maybe you could point me what am I missing in this code?

Comment: try changing         data[$region.attr('id')] = $region.val();
 to         data[$region.attr('name')] = $region.val();

Comment: @medunes when I change it Ajax give me 500 error

Answer (score 0):

So I believe the failure comes, [at least], from the point that you try to fetch the html element from the entire HTTP response object, while you should rather fetch it from the body/content.

From the jQuery Documentation:

> The jqXHR Object The jQuery XMLHttpRequest (jqXHR) object returned by
> $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 is a superset of the browser's native
> XMLHttpRequest object. For example, it contains **responseText** and
> responseXML properties, as well as a getResponseHeader() method. When
> the transport mechanism is something other than XMLHttpRequest (for
> example, a script tag for a JSONP request) the jqXHR object simulates
> native XHR functionality where possible.
>
> (...)
>
> **Data Types**
>
> (...)
>
> The available data types are text, html, xml, json, jsonp, and script.
>
> If text or html is specified, no pre-processing occurs. The data is
> simply passed on to the success handler, and made available through
> the responseText property of the jqXHR object.

This means you have to change this line in your AJAX code:

```
$('#offer_city').replaceWith(
    $(html).find('#offer_city')
);
```

by this line:

```
$('#offer_city').replaceWith(
    $(html.responseText).find('#offer_city')
);
```